# Upload Image to server with React-Native

Tags: react-native, api, postman, form-data, avatar

My name is Leo. I'm trying to upload avatar to server. I find that everyone always use Formdata to upload. But in my case i need 2 key in form-data  (avt, email), so how can i deal with that. Thank you very much!

Here are my testing in Postman
[image]

Comment: Which postman version are you using? The latest version (9.1.5) will automatically add content-type to Each key-value pair, that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For your use-case, you can build the `formData` like:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('avt', {
  name: '<file_name>',
  type: '<file_type>', // e.g. 'image/png'
  uri: '<file_uri>',
});

data.append('email', 'test@email.com');
```

If you are using `fetch` to make the API request, then your request can be like:

```
fetch('<api_url>', {
  method: '<api request method>',
  body: data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    // ...other headers
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('upload file response: ', response)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('upload file error: ', error);
  });
```

If you are using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make the API request, then your request can be like:

```
axios({
  url: '<api_url>',
  method: '<api request method>',
  data: data,
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('upload file response: ', response)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('upload file error: ', error);
  });
```